# Latent Semantic Analysis/Indexing Library for C++

Tags: c++, nlp, lsa

Is there a C++ library for LSA/LSI? Preferably MIT, BSD, Apache,... license - no GPL.

Comment: If you're on OS X you may be able to use the built-in latent semantic mapping C library: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Reference/LatentSemanticMapping/index.html

Comment: I need something platform independent.

Answer (score 2):

There are several C/C++ implementations of Latent Diriclet Allocation (LDA), Latent Semantic Analysis (LSA) and Topic Modelling listed on David Blei's page. http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html and on Berry and Dumai's page http://web.eecs.utk.edu/research/lsi/

**Here's a short-list of C/C++ implementations:**

- `lda-c` : D. Blei's implementation with variational inference for LDA.
- `class-slda` : C. Wang's implementation of supervised topic models with a categorical response.
- `hdp`: C. Wang's implementation of Hierarchical Dirichlet processes
- `Gibbs Sampling`: Phan and Nguyen's implementation of LDA using Gibbs Sampling
  -`PHP LSA`: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phplsa/
- `lsa_prj`: https://github.com/matpalm/lsa/tree/master/lsa_prj

**If you like a python version with tutorial:**
 see http://www.puffinwarellc.com/index.php/news-and-articles/articles/33-latent-semantic-analysis-tutorial.html?showall=1

Comment: Thanks for references, but David Blei's page and Python's tutorial link is broken.

Comment: Ah, that's because he moved to Columbia from Princeton =) http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html